# Making responsive, layout no floating?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make responsive layout, but it's not going to well for me. I got two elements at the top, i need the first on the be floated left and the second one to the right, but i dont seem to get a good align on both of them.

So my first question is, how can i get a good align on them both on large screen and small screen.

And second question is why do i get a scrollbar on the menu in the small screen and how to prevent it?

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="Top">
        <nav class="pull-left">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 ds

                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">STARTSIDA</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">VÅR VERKSAMHET</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">REFERENSER</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">KUNDER</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">OM OSS</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!--/.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        <div class="Logo pull-right">   <span class="fa fa-cogs"></span>
    <span class="Header">Strand<span>maskin</span>.com</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ws60rp9w/

And if you guys, anyone of you have tips on where to learn responsive im gladly taking all advices.

Comment: What does "*good align*" align mean? Do you have an image of the desired result?

Comment: I don't have a clue what i've done but the align is good now :S So now its the scrollbar problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want top element to go left and right, then check following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <style>
       *{
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
           border: 0;
       }
       .container{
           max-width: 100%;
       }
       .container .top-element-left {
           max-width: 45%;
           background-color: skyblue;
           float: left;
       }
       .top-element-right {
           background-color: skyblue;
           max-width: 45%;
           float: right;
       }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top-element-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad facilis quae nihil perspiciatis atque impedit et, eius, quidem consequatur fugit.</div>
        <div class="top-element-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut laudantium, minus nobis vel dignissimos inventore?</div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and for suggestion for responsive web development: I would suggest you to start using susy. For me life had never been easier when working with css until I stumbled at [susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/)

Comment: Thank you that great solution worked awesome! Now i got the scroll-bar problem

Comment: actually there is confusion in your question that's why i can't help until i see what you have done. if you can make fiddle of your new problem then i can do something!

Comment: When i expand the menu there is a scrollbar, when it fades

Comment: please write a code of that menu specifically in your question... it would be better if you make a fiddle for this specific problem so i could see live!

Comment: Hello again @Lahori, i decided to start over. And now its working just fine with the menu aswell. But is there a other way to do this or do i have to have the 2 menus like i have? http://jsfiddle.net/La32qcjc/

Comment: if you want to target different devices or as many screen sizes as you can, and this is what the Responsive web development is all about, you will have to ,of course, use different layouts for those specific sizes using media queries. for fast development I already suggested you to use susy extension.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help @Lahori