# Text overflow with two div elements side by side

Tags: html, css, element

I have made this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VincentWilkie/w302joLz/) to demonstrate something close to what I currently have.

What I'm looking for is an ellipsis on the left `div` of a row that sits beside the right `div` so that it does not overlap (I realize `position` is probably not going to work here). Both have dynamic text. I am willing to change said elements, if necessary.

**EDIT:** I need part one of the first line to be on only one line and overflow when it overlaps part two. So far the answers have not provided a means to do this. I would set static widths if the content of the divs were static. I *might* be able to get away with setting a static width for the second `div` as the possibilities for content in it are limited.

**Note:** The column width changes in size based on browser dimensions. Also, it's absolutely positioned because of other containers/elements that exist on the page. (Probably not ideal)

**Another Note:** The column could have many `row`s so I'm only showing a couple for example purposes.

Here is some example code:

```css
.col {
    background-color: pink;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 400px;
}

.row {
    background-color: #9595E4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px 8px;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.row-top {
    position: relative;
    height: 19px;
    line-height: 19px;
}

.row-top .one {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.row-top .two {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-top">
            <div class="one">
                This is the first line, part one, which overlaps
            </div>
            <div class="two">
                1st line, part two
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>This is the second line</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-top">
            <div class="one">
                This content could be really really really really long
            </div>
            <div class="two">
                1st line, part two
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>This is the second line</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-top">
            <div class="one">
                Or it could be short
            </div>
            <div class="two">
                1st line, part two
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>This is the second line</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I needed with the this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VincentWilkie/w302joLz/8/)

Here is the code:

```css
.col {
    background-color: pink;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 400px;
}

.row {
    background-color: #9595E4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px 8px;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.row-top {
    position: relative;
    height: 19px;
    line-height: 19px;
}

.row-top .one {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 125px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.row-top .two {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #ccc;
    max-width: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-top">
            <div class="one">
                This is the first line, part one, which overlaps
            </div>
            <div class="two">
                1st line, part two
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>This is the second line</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-top">
            <div class="one">
                This is the first line, part one, which overlaps
            </div>
            <div class="two">
                1st line, part two
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>This is the second line</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added `max-width: 125px` to the second `div` and changed `right` to `125px` on the first `div` to compensate. The problem with this would be if the second `div` had content less than or greater than 125px.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with css: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Solution with jquery plugin: http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

Comment: If you have only one line is simple, add this example class to all element you don't want overlap: `.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}`

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring one column & inside it two rows which is technically wrong. on the contrary you should declare one row and make as many columns as you want (in this case only two since you want only left and right elements to sit side-by-side). Recently i answered a scenario like this [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263892/making-responsive-layout-no-floating/33264571#33264571)

Comment: @Vincent Wilkie yup. but then you would have one element per row which is not the requirement in this case. right?